# Crystal Report NOT Clause

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

I am trying to run a crystal report 8 with the following sql clause. This query runs fine and gives me the accurate results when using query analyzer.

```
  `WHERE(A_INVENTORY.Location_Id = 'JNARC')
   AND (([A_INVENTORY].[Pocket_Inv] <=
                A_INVENTORY.Par_Level_Inv)
        AND NOT (A_INVENTORY.Pocket_Inv >=
                    A_INVENTORY.Max_Pocket_Inv))`
```

However, when I pass this clause in Crystal reports 8, it does not save my NOT clause. Any suggestions please.

```
{A_INVENTORY.Location_Id} = "JNARC" and
({A_INVENTORY.Par_Level_Inv} <= {A_INVENTORY.Pocket_Inv}) AND
(NOT ({A_INVENTORY.Pocket_Inv} >= {A_INVENTORY.Max_Pocket_Inv}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Entering the opposite information under the "supress" of the "detail" section worked for me. The report will query all the records but suppress all data that fits the entered criteria.